# Inheritance and nested class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, nested

I'm trying to implement different versions of a data structure. Suppose it has an interface shown below (it's simplified):

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Base {
 public:
  class Iterator {
    virtual auto operator*() -> T& = 0;
  };

 public:
  virtual auto Find(const T& value) -> Iterator = 0;
}
```

Now I want to inherit a class that will implement it:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base<T> {
 public:
  class Iterator {
    auto operator*() -> T& override {
      /* ... */
    }
  };

 public:
  auto Find(const T& value) -> Iterator override {
    /* ... */
  };
}
```

Problem is that I need to implement `Iterator` based on what `Derived` does, but `Find` function's signature brakes because of `Derived::Iterator` (it should be `Base::Iterator`). Is there a way to do so or do I have to give up on using interface class?

Comment: Suppose you managed to implement it somehow. How would a caller holding `Base<int>* pb` pointer (pointing to `Derived<int>`, or perhaps another implementation) use `Find`? It would call `auto iter = pb->Find(42);` - now what? What can it do with `iter`? Your design doesn't say.

Comment: Sorry, fixed `Iterator` interface. Now caller can dereference `iter` like so: `auto value = *iter;`.

Comment: `Find` purports to return an instance of an abstract class by value. That can't possibly work, as it's impossible to create an instance of an abstract class. The interface you propose is fundamentally unimplementable.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, what you are trying to achieve is related to type erasure or maybe static polymorphism. You want Base::Iterator to be a non-abstract generalized type, that can be constructed from any Derived implementation.

This is a dynamic solution that you can optimize based on your needs

```
template<typename T>
struct Base
{
// This is the interface that needs to be implemented by the derived class' iterator
    struct IIterator
    {
        virtual T& Get() = 0;
    };
// this is the generalized type that needs to be returned by find()
    struct Iterator
    {
        Iterator(std::unique_ptr<IIterator> impl ):
            _impl(std::move(impl))
        {
        }

        T& operator*() { _impl->Get(); }

        private:
// You can implement small struct optimization by making a byte array big enough
// to store any of the implementations and avoid dynamic memory
        std::unique_ptr<IIterator> _impl;
    };

    virtual Iterator find() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
struct Derived : public Base<T>
{
// Now in derived we implement our iterator
    struct IteratorImpl : Base<T>::IIterator
    {
        IteratorImpl(T* p) : ptr(p) {}

        T& Get() override { return *ptr; }
        T* ptr;
    };

    typename Base<T>::Iterator find() override
    {
        IteratorImpl result(nullptr);
// After finding we need to construct the generalized type from the implementation
        return typename Base<T>::Iterator(std::make_unique<IteratorImpl>( result ));
    }
};
```

Another way to do something like that is by using templates and CRTP to make a static interface. CRTP is a technique that involves passing the derived type information back to the base class using it's template arguments and using that information to define or find an implementation for the Base iterator based on the derived type.